# partial google sheets string cell comparison

Tags: google-sheets

The Primary Sheet has basic info ( narrowed here ), including 
Column B - a flag to say "Yes" or "No/Stop"
Column C  - a Company Name

A Second sheet "stopphrases" will have a growing list of words and phrases in it. If one of these words match first sheet called "data" > Column C (Company Name), Column B will updated to a "No"

IE - 
1) If stopphrases!sheet, range A1:A25 contains "UPS"
2) And the Primary Sheet has "UPS Shipping"
This "partial" match should catch it and insert flag into data.Column B

=MATCH("*"&stopphrases!A1:A10&"*", C6,0)

I seem to be able to check a partial from a single cell and check the range, but not got the other way - get the partial words from multiple cells and check against a single cell.

I also tried
(If Statement)
=IF(COUNTA(IFERROR(FILTER(stopphrases!$A$1:$A$25,stopphrases!$A$1:$A$25=C2))),"Yes","No")

The results I am looking for are
So again - 
IF StopPhrases!A1:A25 Range has a phrase "UPS"
THen any entry in first sheet, Company Name, Column B that CONTAINS "UPS" - IE "UPS Shipping" should flag - this way I can run a condition.

The end result is if a match occurs a "stop" happens and that record doesn't get processed in other spreadsheets that are connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regexmatch or regexextract to do this:

first to make the dynamic list of stopphrases you use a `JOIN` function, an `INDIRECT` function so you  can use `COUNTA` to allow for it to automatically add the correct number of phrases,

```
 =JOIN("|",INDIRECT("E2:E"&COUNTA(E2:E)+1))
```

Then you use arrayformula and regexmatch to dynamically match your list of stop words:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISTEXT(B1:B),if(REGEXMATCH(B1:B,$D$1),"STOP","GO"),))
```

[image]

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISTEXT(B1:B),if(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(B1:B),$D$1),"STOP","GO"),))

Comment: thanks so much Aurielle - I'm reviewing and testing this now! I may have a question but as soon as I verify I'll be back here

Comment: Your my hero, @Aurielle Perlmann ! One little thing I can't figure out - Case sensitive. For example if altx or alt was added to stop phrase - A1 would still say Go. If "Alt" or "Altx" was added to stop phrase - A1 would change to STOP - I did neglect to mention that I didn't want it case sensitive.

Comment: I meant to ask you about that you can wrap it in lower. I adjusted my answer up top

Comment: I did actually try lower() before I asked but all my variations turned to GO - I realize that all stop words must be entered in lower case for that to work. However the most important is you solved my array and regex. thanks so much @aurielle-perlmann . Excellent solution for me!

Comment: you can also wrap the reference to your joined regex in lower() if you dont want to rewrite all of them

Comment: it's perfect - it's a beginning solution. However - I just brought this into my real world scenario and get all stops. **Your answer still stands and answers my question exactly**.. but by chance - I actually am using a IF statement to pull the "Company Name" from another cell - based on logic that sets D4 to one of two options. 
=IF(D4 = "SHIPPER", L4, 
     IF(D4 = "CONSIGNEE", M4, "SKIP"
       )
    )
Any advice in getting it to work where there are vlookups and not values in Company Name?

Comment: would you be able to share a sample sheet? im sure I have an answer for you but its difficult to guess without seeing what your referring to - pretend data is find too

Comment: I don't have enough points to chat so I had to narrow in and sanitize data and setup the scenario. You can find the sample spreadsheet at [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jWbEteU9JglNtGnleKrbcKoHveuu95qCqAPPp8mVCd8/edit?usp=sharing]
Sheet that says "Yippee-Solution'Auri" is your solution working
Sheet that is "targetData1" is your solution but the if/conditions so all is stop email. The two green sheets and stop phrase orange tab are the only ones to focus for you

Comment: The minor problem above for anyone reading I had was unrelated to the answer @Aurielle-Perlmann provided. The answer was not affected by vlookups or values as mentioned.